# Is there a way to pass templated function signature as a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

By using template template parameters one can pass to a class a templated class without specifying types on its parameters. I was wondering is there a way to pass into a template template parameter a templated signature of a function to be able to specialize which variant of the function is to be considered forward.

To be clear - I know I cannot do that:

```
template <class T>
void foo() { /*...*/ }

template <template <class...> class FooType>
struct Foo { /*...*/ };

int main() {
    Foo<decltype(foo)> f;
}
```

But somehow I would like to be able to pass templated signature of function to `Foo`. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example below one has a template template parameter that accepts the preferred signature for the function.
Because of the specialization and the lack of a body for the template class, only types for callables are accepted.
It is a generalization of what the OP actually asked:

```
#include<cassert>

template<typename F>
struct S;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct S<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R(*)(Args...);
};

template<template<typename> class F>
struct T {
    typename F<void(int)>::type ft;
    typename F<double(double, double)>::type gt;
};

void f(int) { }
double g(double x, double y) { return x+y; }

int main() {
    T<S> t;
    t.ft = f;
    t.gt = g;
    t.ft(42);
    auto v = t.gt(1., 1.);
    assert(v == 2.);
}
```

Comment: Yes the `using` does the trick here. This approach seems to be even cleaner than templated `using`...

Comment: Can I ask you what you are using it for? Just curiosity... I can't see an use for `T` where I can't use simply `S`.

Comment: Of course, the question rose from another archive question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655835/better-pattern-for-partial-specialization-disambiguation-precedence-chain/36657353#36657353 I wanted to propose a general tag that would be able to accept both template template class and function with a given signature... Then I realized that this is not a trivial task... :)

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't believe that this is not possible so I searched a bit and found a way to do exactly what I wanted. I used templated `using` with a syntax:

```
template <template<class... Args> class FooType>
struct Foo {
   FooType<int> ft;
};

template <class Res, class... Args>
using FooSignature = Res(*)(Args...);

int foo() {
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   Foo<FooSignature> f;
   f.ft = foo;
}
```

This however still leaves the question how can this be possible since the standard states something opposite.

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574164/955273)

> Template of function pointer is illegal in C++

The C++ Standard says in $14/1,

> A template defines a family of classes or functions.

Further quoting from the linked answer:

> Please note that it does NOT say "A template defines a family of classes, functions **or function pointers**"

However, you can pass concrete function pointers, and specialise on their signature:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void foo(T) { }

template <typename>
struct Foo;

template<typename T> 
struct Foo<void(T)> 
{
    void cb() { std::cout << "T\n"; }
};

template<> 
struct Foo<void(int)> 
{
    void cb() { std::cout << "int\n"; }
};

template<> 
struct Foo<void(double)> 
{
    void cb() { std::cout << "double\n"; }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo<decltype(foo<int   >)>().cb(); // outputs 'int'
    Foo<decltype(foo<double>)>().cb(); // outputs 'double'
    Foo<decltype(foo<char  >)>().cb(); // outputs 'T'
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

template of template is still a template.

```
template <class T>
void foo() { /*...*/ }

template <typename T>
struct Foo { /*...*/ };

int main() {
    Foo<decltype(foo<int>)> f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a function template as an argument. What you *can* do is wrap a function template in a generate lambda taking a tag parameter:

```
template <class T> struct tag_t { using type = T; };

template <class T>
void foo() { ... }

template <class F>
void call_func_with(F f) {
    f(tag_t<int>{} );
    f(tag_t<double>{} );
}

call_with_func([](auto tag) { foo<decltype(tag)::type>(); } );
```

Here, `f(tag_t<X>{} )` ends up calling `foo<X>()`, as desired.