# Prospective destructors in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, destructor

I have this code and this outputs the following:

link to the following example
https://godbolt.org/z/z8Pn9GsTv

```
template <typename T>
struct A1 {
    A1() {
        std::cout << "construction of a1" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A1() {
        std::cout << "destruction of a1" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A1() requires (std::is_same_v<T,int>) {
        std::cout << "it is an int" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A1 <int>a;
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
construction of a1
destruction of a1
```

but swapping places of destructors it gives other result:

link to the code
https://godbolt.org/z/vxj7dPqaj

```
template <typename T>
struct A1 {
    A1() {
        std::cout << "construction of a1" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A1() requires (std::is_same_v<T,int>) {
        std::cout << "it is an int" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A1() {
        std::cout << "destruction of a1" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

output:

```
construction of a1
it is an int
```

wondering is this a bug?

Comment: It's a clang bug - https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50570 .

Comment: The bug is now active here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/45614

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's indeed a reported Clang bug<sup>1</sup>, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72269321/prospective-destructors-in-c#comment127679652_72269321) by [Quimby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7691729/quimby).

Note that the second snippet (the one with the the constrained destructor first) doesn't really "work" in Clang, which just ignores the second destructor<sup>2</sup>.

Also note that, unlike gcc, at the moment I'm writing, Clang doesn't seem to have implemented [[P0848R3](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0848r3.html)] (which is about conditional trivial special member functions) yet<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1) https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50570</sup>
<sup>2) See e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/rff7qfK65</sup>
<sup>3) See the reported values of the [feature test](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations#__cpp_concepts) macro `__cpp_concepts`, e.g. here: https://godbolt.org/z/P4z3Pj5vT</sup>

Answer (score -2):

In your 2'nd code,

Try changing this:

```
A1 <int>a;
```

To this:

```
A1 <double>a;
```

And you'll get the output:

```
construction of a1
destruction of a1 // With MSVC & GCC compiler
```

My interpretation here is that when the condition for the first constructor (with `requires`) fails, the 2'nd constructor is called which prints `"destruction of a1"` and destroys `a`.

[Here is a more detailed explanation...](https://www.sandordargo.com/blog/2021/06/16/multiple-destructors-with-cpp-concepts)

Comment: That's not the output one gets, Clang emits an error about an unsatisfied constraint.

Comment: Yes true. Clang has a bug. I've mentioned the behavior that's correct according to me. I'll mention the compiler.

Answer (score -5):

On your class template, you have two destructors definition recipe. During instantiation the The compiler gets the "first" recipe that match the signature needed. Depending the compiler depending the result. I think clang, gcc and mingw will provide the same result, msvc approach is different. [Better pattern for partial specialization disambiguation precedence chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655835/better-pattern-for-partial-specialization-disambiguation-precedence-chain)

Comment: "_The compiler gets the "first" recipe that match the signature needed. Depending the compiler depending the result._": No, that's not how it works. The order of declarations is supposed to be irrelevant. I don't know how the linked CWG issue is supposed to relate.

Comment: "A1 <int>a; generates ~A1<int>() requires (std::is_same_v<T,int>){...} first and ~A1<int>(){...} after. both are valid. Which one is selected first according to the standard?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @abdeldiaz Normal overload resolution is applied (see https://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#4) If `std::is_same_v<T,int>` is satisfied, then the first overload is chosen since it is more constrained than the other (https://www.eel.is/c++draft/over#match.best.general-2.6). If it not satisfied than the other one, since it is the only viable overload. Overload resolution doesn't depend on the order of declarations. If the resolution was ambiguous the program would simply be ill-formed and should fail to compile.